# Attributing numeric values to a character vector

Tags: r, vector, merge

I have two vectors but I only want to work with the character one. How can I assign the values of this numeric vector

```
weekly.hours <- c(10, 20, 15, 30, 5, 25) 
x <- weekly.hours
```

to this one

```
names <- c("Maria", "Jose", "Joao", "Pedro", "Luisa", "Joana")
y <- names
```

so that 10 is assigned to Maria, 20 to Jose, and so on?

I ultimately want to run comparisons like `y >= 15` and have the following return:

```
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE.
```

Comment: What is the point if your `names` vector? Going on your desired output, `y <- x` is what you are looking for. More likely `y <- x; names(x) <- names` is what you want.

Comment: You could put them in a `data.frame` together. `dat <- data.frame(names, weekly.hours)` and then do `dat[dat$weekly.hours >= 15,]` to look at the subset of all your data at once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are after a list of people who have worked 15 hours or more

```
library(dplyr)

weekly.hours <- c(10, 20, 15, 30, 5, 25) 
names <- c("Maria", "Jose", "Joao", "Pedro", "Luisa", "Joana")


df <- data.frame(weekly.hours = weekly.hours,
                 names = names)

df <- df %>% filter(weekly.hours >= 15)
```

To specifically get a vector of the names of people who worked 15 hours or more

```
df$names
```

Comment: Cheers, Gregor. That is what I needed. Moving on now.